# Empty plot in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I am trying to plot Reflection coefficient by using this formula:

[image]

**Code:**

```
E1=1;
E2=2.32*E1; 

for tetai=1:90      
    numerator=cos(tetai)-(sqrt(E2/E1).*sqrt(1-(E1/E2).*sin(tetai)^2));
    denominator=cos(tetai)+(sqrt(E2/E1).*sqrt(1-(E1/E2).*sin(tetai)^2));
    eta=numerator/denominator;
    plot(tetai,eta,'r');
    hold on
end     

title('Plots')
xlabel('\Theta')
ylabel('\Gamma')
```

After repeating E2 values with 2.56, 4, 9, 16, 25, and 81 I should obtain the following result (At first step I just wanted to obtain a single value with E2=2.32):

[image]

But unfortunately, there is no graphics on the plot result screen. So, what is the mistake?

**Note:** I use MATLAB R2015a

Comment: You are plotting *points* here instead of a line. To visualize the points, change your plot command to something like this `plot(tetai,eta,'o');` Also note that `sin` assumes that you're inputting the angle in *radians*. Also read the documentation of `sind`. However it would be better if you store all the values in a loop and plot them in a single command outside the loop as suggested by lyang

Comment: @Sardar_Usama Salam Serdar, why do not post your code as answer and comment your explanation on code as lyang? Thanks...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Mistakes:**

1. You're using [**`sin`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sin.html) and [**`cos`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cos.html) and inputting angle in degrees. Either convert the angle or even better use the functions dedicated for this purpose. i.e [**`sind`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sind.html) and [**`cosd`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cosd.html) respectively.
2. You don't see anything in output because you're plotting point by point. For that, some [**marker**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html#input_argument_LineSpec) should've been specified. But anyway, what you want to plot is not this. You want to plot a line instead.
3. Another problem in using `plot` is that you are not plotting what you think you should be plotting. The image that you showed in the question is a plot between **|Γᵇ⊥|** and **θᵢ** , not **Γᵇ⊥** and **θᵢ**

**Fixed code:**

```
E1=1;
E2i=[2.32, 2.56, 4, 9, 16, 25, 81];

gamma = zeros(1,91);    %Pre-allocation
for k=1:7
    E2 = E2i(k);

    for theta_i=0:90
        numerator=cosd(theta_i)- sqrt((E2/E1)*(1-(E1/E2)*sind(theta_i)^2));
        denominator=cosd(theta_i)+ sqrt((E2/E1)*(1-(E1/E2)*sind(theta_i)^2));
        gamma(theta_i+1)=numerator/denominator;    
    end

    plot(0:90,abs(gamma));
    hold on;
    text(45,abs(gamma(45)),['\epsilon_2/\epsilon_1  = ',num2str(E2/E1)]);
end

title('Plots');  xlabel('\theta_i (degrees)');  ylabel('|\Gamma^b_\perp|');
```

**Output:**

[image: Output]

Comment: I also tried to add text as on the graph by using **text(E2i(k),0,'\leftarrow E2i(k)')** but now working. How can I do that?

Comment: Read the documentation of [**`text`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html)

Comment: I had already read before asking the question, but not make the parameters to be displayed. I tried **text(pi,0,'\leftarrow sin(\pi)')** on [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html) page. Any idea?

Comment: You just copy pasted from that page without trying to understand which input argument means what

Comment: No, of course I tried to understand and tried as I posted 2 post before: **text(E2i(k),0,'\leftarrow E2i(k)')**.

Comment: why did you write `E2i(k)`, why `0` ! clearly you showed no effort

Comment: I tried many different combinations, but the example is not using a look and display loop values :( I also re tried again, but not worked.

Comment: yeah that's the problem that you're randomly trying. Read the documentation and try to learn and understand which input argument is for what

Comment: Also trying to following [this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/38164-using-text-function-in-a-for-loop). Why do not help?

Comment: @ClintEastwood I have edited the answer. But remember that ***SO is not a free code writing service***

Answer (score 1):

You can try create a nan vector outside the loop, fill the vector in the iterations, and plot outside the loop.

```
E1=1;
E2=2.32*E1; 
Data=nan(90);

for tetai=1:90      
    numerator=cos(tetai)-(sqrt(E2/E1).*sqrt(1-(E1/E2).*sin(tetai)^2));
    denominator=cos(tetai)+(sqrt(E2/E1).*sqrt(1-(E1/E2).*sin(tetai)^2));
    eta=numerator/denominator;
    Data(tetai)=eta;
end     

plot(Data, 'r');
title('Plots')
xlabel('\Theta')
ylabel('\Gamma')
```

Edited on phone, not tested.

Comment: Seems to be good idea, but as I am really new in MATLAB, could you please post an example? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Thanks, but the plot result is not seems to be as posted above. Have you tested it?

Comment: Anyway, also thanks to you for your good approach and vote up :)

Comment: @Sardar_Usama I followed your posted answer of this question, but the approach in lyang's answer is also useful. So, do not worry :)